# How to define the alignment of icon and description inside a C# button?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

currently I'm working on building a GUI in C# and .NET using MS Visual Studio.

As a control element I added a button (a DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonItem) which consists of an icon and a short descriptive text:

[image: Current style of the control element. Icon and text horizontally aligned instead of vertically.]

However, I'd like to have icon and description vertically aligned rather than horizontally but havn't found a way to do so yet. Can anybody give me a clue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it, I must have had overread it multiple times - sorry, for bothering you.

It's just the parameter 'ImagePosition' under 'Apperance' in the object properties.